# How to convert Ruby hash rocket into a valid JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I try to get this kind of JSON data:

```
[
   {
      "id":3,
      "foods": [{'id':2,'name':'Nasi Minyak','qty':6},{'id':14,'name':'Kuey teow','qty':3}]
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "foods": [{'id':2,'name':'Nasi Minyak','qty':1},{'id':14,'name':'Kuey teow','qty':1}]
   }
]
```

Please note that there is no double quote `"` at the beginning and at the end of the `foods` object.

What I have now is like this:

```
[
       {
          "id":3,
          "foods": "[{:id=>2, :name=>"Nasi Minyak", :qty=>6}, {:id=>14, :name=>"Kuey teow", :qty=>3}]"
       },
       {
          "id":4,
          "foods": "[{:id=>2, :name=>"Nasi Minyak", :qty=>1}, {:id=>14, :name=>"Kuey teow", :qty=>1}]"
       }
    ]
```

Obviously, it's a string and not an array like I want. This give me problem because I need to use this JSON data for the front-end of my app (built using Angular and play a lot with AJAX / `$http`).

I have this inside my controller:

```
class Api::OrderController < ApplicationController

    # GET /api/orders
    def index
        @orders = Order.all

        render json: @orders
    end

end
```

And this is my order_serializer file.

```
class OrderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :foods
end
```

What I have tried:

**Attempt #1**

I try to change my order model into something like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :foods, Array
end
```

And after that I try to `update_attributes` the `foods` using rails console like this:

```
o.update_attributes :foods => [{'id':2,'name':'Nasi Minyak','qty':6},{'id':14,'name':'Kuey teow','qty':3}]
```

But that's didn't work for me. The JSON data is still in hash rocket.

**Attempt #2**

I try `to_json`. But it's still didn't work.

How to get rid of the double quote `"` marks and save valid JSON array correctly inside Rails?

**Note**:

The `foods` column inside my database is `text`. Not `string`. I believe it's not related to this problem.

I found this [tutorial](http://www.rexfeng.com/blog/2012/12/convert-a-ruby-hash-into-valid-json/) but I couldn't see way to do it.

Comment: Is there any use case I am missing here for not having `Food` as a separate model and then associating `Order` with it?

Comment: A string and text in a database are the same. One could possibly be a fixed-length string but still, they're equivalent once they land inside Ruby.

Comment: @Surya I don't have `Food` model. The `foods` data will be pushed from front-end side. `Order` model just save it without any associations.

Comment: Doesn't `serialize` want something like `JSON` or `Marshal`? I'm not sure `Array` is a valid serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class called Food and another one called OrderItem and then in your Order class you should define a relation:

```
has_many :order_items
has_many :food, :through => order_items
```

This way you have two separate classes: Order and Food and through the OrderItem class you create a relation between them, this way you keep the logic separated.

Each food would have its own name and id, but the quantity would go to the OrderItem table.

Comment: Could you add some more? Still didn't get it. It would be super helpful if you can share some code too.

Comment: Give this a read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

If you separate your models this way you should have no work at all when converting them to json

Comment: Say I add `create` method after this inside this API controller and this `create` method is receiving `POST` request from my front-end app with param data like `[{"id":2,"name":"Nasi Minyak","qty":10},{"id":14,"name":"Kuey teow","qty":10}]`, how do `Order` capture it and pass the `qty` to OrderItem?

Comment: You can use the JSON.parse method to parse the json data you're receiving, and then create both Order and OrderItem objects with the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
render json: @orders.to_json
```

if your app is an API, try using `active_model_serializers` gem.
it returns the model serialized.

Updated:

```
class OrderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :foods
end

render json: @orders
```

Comment: Already use `to_json` and `active_model_serializers`. But still didn't work.

Comment: Can you put your OrderSerializer please?

Comment: Still not working. It's still in string and have double quote `"` marks.